# Result missing in solr for specific search term

Tags: solr

I am seeing a problem in a solr search where a result is not returned for a specific search term. The page has definitely been indexed by solr and is returned for other searches, including for a single word in that phrase.

eg:

search 'abc 123' - page IS NOT in the results

search 'abc' - page IS in the results

The phrase 'abc 123' is in the field that is indexed for the page title / h1 tag. The main content of the page and the page URL.

These results have been observed by querying the solr box directly.

Im a relative n00b to solr, any help much appreciated

Comment: Which version of solr are you using? can u give example of data set? and what is the field type of that particular field?

Comment: take a look at the analysis page. Try to index the portion 'abc 123' and then search it as well. Check the indexing pipeline steps and see if there any quirks.

Comment: 5.2.1, unfortunately cant give data set, they are text fields / areas 

ive looked at the analysis page , not sure how to reindex from here. Havere-index numerous times via the CMS interface.

Comment: further debugging has resutled in some interesting results  

the problem only arises when the search term includes a two digit number.   

I have created 3 pieces of content and changed the config so it is only indexing title.   

euan 1 - works fine  
euan 12 - doesnt work  
euan 123 - works fine  
euan - works fine (all 3 pages returned)